# How do banks and dealers effectively hedge a variance swap?

Tags: hedging, delta-hedging, variance-swap

It is known that a variance swap can be replicated by a strip of options. However, it is costly to trade that many OTM options and there is not enough liquidity to trade the wings in the quantity that is necessary. So I suppose banks do not actually trade the entire strip. The question is then, how do they hedge this position?
Do they hedge the BS delta of the variance swap and trade a 25d put against it or something similar?

Comment: Does [JPM](http://docs.sbossu.com/bossu-strasser-guichard-varswap.pdf), section 2. Valuation and Hedging in Pratice help? Also, the practical difficulties in replicating the actual log payout across strikes, is the reason that the market for equity index varswaps usually trades at a basis to the replicating portfolio.

Comment: It is more or less as @AKdemy wrote. I used to trade varswaps as a buyside ptf.mgr. There was always a basis especially for longer tenors. This basis could be attributed to the impact of interest rates (can't take them to be deterministic anymore for longer dated), but especially the fact you replicate only up to a certain strike. I am not aware of an easy way to calculate this basis, but one way could be: simulate the payoffs of the discrete replicating portfolio and calc the mismatch wrt to the continuous replicating portfolio. Add the mean of this difference to the price.

Comment: @Frido, I am interested in reading more about that - i.e. how how the pricing is done in practice and the differences to the theoretical continuous replicating portfolio price. Any resources you can think off?

Comment: @phdstudent Well there is this open access paper, and references therein might be relevant as well. I haven't spent much time on this yet to be honest, but it's an interesting and practically relevant subject: https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/11/1/11

Comment: @Frido It is not the pricing I am discussing though. I am more interested in how dealers hedge the exposure to the variance swap knowing that they will not trade the entire strip against it.

Comment: @Rodrigo I know, that's what both AKdemy and my comments tried to address. Since you can't hedge with the theoretical strip you simulate the P/L distribution of the difference between realized variance (payoff the continuous strip) and the payoff of the discrete strip. The mean of this difference, or some other related number, you (or the bank) then add to the price of the theoretical strip, this price you quote to the client, and you hedge with the discrete portfolio.

Comment: @Frido You are still implying they try to replicate the payoff of the var with a strip.. whcih I assume they actually do not. As for the basis, I am sure there is one, mainly wen vols are low, but it is more driven by offer/demand than some difference in theoretical pnl from a discrete strip